# Signal junction

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I don't understand the meaning of SIGNAL JUNCTION in this context.

Would you please explain the meaning of this word?

http://www.dubainews.net/index.php/sid/237936775

The project is set for completion in the second quarter of 2016.The first part of the project covers the extension of Hessa Road that will stretch for 4km with two lanes in each direction. It starts from Remraam Residential Project up to the existing roundabout at the entry to Dubai Sports City, which will be converted to ***a signal junction***.

Thank you.

Comment: It just means they'll change the *roundabout* to a crossroads junction controlled by *traffic lights*. A bit odd, since "progress" usually goes the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refers to a **road-junction** that is controlled by **light signals**.

[image]